Dynamics 365 Delta Link expiration and Delta Token structure
I have successfully setup Dynamics 365 to allow change tracking for a specific table.
On each request, the API returns the delta link to retrieve the subsequent changes. The delta link contains the Delta Token.
Delta Token structure is :
[Version Number] + [!] + [Server Timestamp at response]
https://[API URL]/api/data/v9.0/accounts?$deltatoken=30045728!10/17/2024 08:46:33

I am unclear, about the usage of the "Timestamp" part in the Delta Token. Through some tests, I have seen that its specifically the timestamp part, that serves as a mechanism for validating the request if its expired or not. By default, if the timestamp is within the last 7 days the request is valid otherwise is considered expired.
However, if for the next request to get the changes, we use a new delta token, by retaining the "Version number" of the delta token we received earlier, and replacing the timestamp part with the current timestamp, the API considers it valid and returns the changed data.
I have used a delta token, with a Version Number I received 2 weeks ago, and just manipulating the timestamp, using the current timestamp, the API still returns all the changed data.
I find this confusing and not logical.
Is there another purpose to the timestamp or just a very simple mechanism of expiry checking that eventually does not have any real value, as you we can just replace it with the current timestamp and avoid the expiration error?
